# What is the difference between using usual website and the same website pinned to home screen?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, cocoscreator

I'm developing html5/js game using Cocos Creator and all looks fine and works great when I run it in Safari browser on my iPhone 5s or iPhone 6s.

The problem is, when I pin my game website to home screen, I gain quick access to it and nice fullscreen mode, but all the animations becoming slower. It is just a prototype of a game, so there are no difficult or long animations, but my game website still working much slower from "pinned mode". Another one problem: looks like pinned mode has it's own "cache". I've updated game sources on a server and my changes are visible in usual Safari mode and from Chrome browser, but pinned mode still showing old version of a game. I cleared all caches I know about, I even unpinned and pinned it few times - nothing changed.

Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue and it is not fixed yet:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/31599